# React Native element's position is wrong in Testflight version

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I don't understand why the positionning of these elements changes on the Testflight version of my app like bellow, it is supposed to be all aligned on the same line.

I am unable to reproduce this bug on both real device and simulator but when I open my app in Testflight, it shows.

Any idea what this could be linked to?

Here is my code:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <SafeAreaView />
  <View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 5}}>
    <ButtonIcon
      uri={require('../../image/filter.png')}
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('FilterModal', {activityType: activityType})}
    />
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <SearchBar search={search} onChange={(value) => setSearch(value)} />
    </View>
    <ButtonIcon
      uri={require('../../image/add.png')}
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Activity')}
    />
  </View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `SafeAreaView` Component is probably messing with your layout depending if it is on a device with a notch or not.  You need to place your other code **inside** the `SafeAreaView` to prevent this:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}} />
  <View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 5}}>
    <ButtonIcon
      uri={require('../../image/filter.png')}
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('FilterModal', {activityType: activityType})}
    />
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <SearchBar search={search} onChange={(value) => setSearch(value)} />
    </View>
    <ButtonIcon
      uri={require('../../image/add.png')}
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Activity')}
    />
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
```